# Node.js - Mistake in my code - Any idea how to fix this?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning how to use Node.js and I find myself not being able to fix this code.
I can't find the solution to this. Could someone help me?

```
'use strict';

module.exports.multiplyRange = (event, context, callback) => {

    var start = event.start;
    var end = event.end;

    // This is where I'm having problems
    
    var range = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        range = range.push(i);
    }

    let multiply = (a, b) => a + b;
    var result = l.reduce(multiply);

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: {
            result: result,
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: What is this line? var result = l.reduce(multiply); @Maritim

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Lion Pardon? I simply edited the question to improve the code formatting. The question is from Diego, not myself.

Comment: Sorry, I confused, thanks, yeah to @Diego

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there are two significant issues:

1. `range = range.push(i);` There is no value returned by the push method. As a result, you should not assign a value to the range variable in this case.
2. `l.reduce(multiply);` The variable 'l' is not defined in this case. This variable must be replaced with the 'range' variable.

Please find the following code, which has been updated and is now working:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.multiplyRange = (event, context, callback) => {

    var start = event.start;
    var end = event.end;

    // This is where I'm having problems
    
    var range = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }

    let multiply = (a, b) => a + b;
    var result = range.reduce(multiply);

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: {
            result: result,
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: "There is no value returned by the push method." << strictly this is not true. There is a value returned, which is the new length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line will be buggy.
[image]

You should change this one as range instead of "l".
And I think multiply functional also not true.

But anyhow, I am not sure expected logic, however, this line could be buggy one.
var result = l.reduce(multiply);

Thanks

Comment: Please put code in text in your answers, not in images. Code should not be in images here.  It can't be searched.  It can't be copied/pasted.  In images, it doesn't work well on mobile, etc...